# How to display progress bar in windows phone 8 for images sourced from the web?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have a list of URIs of images on Flickr. I use gestures in the Windows phone Toolkit to display images and handle the flick event. Since the images are on the web the source is set fine, but the progress bar collapses (hides) immediately on flick since it has already set the source of the image and phone still has to download and show it.

I wish to display the progress bar until the image is fully visible. (is using a WebClient useful?)

Here is a simple video to show exactly what is happening. Don't mind the pictures, I just picked up the first thing which came up.

[Video Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6rAytiKgXwU)

The code is below:

```
  private void GestureListener_Flick(object sender, FlickGestureEventArgs e)
                {
                    if (((e.Angle <= 180 && e.Angle >= 135) || (e.Angle < 225 && e.Angle > 180)) && e.Direction.ToString().Equals("Horizontal"))
                    {
                        progess_bar.Visibility=Visibility.Visible;
                        if(index<photoslist.Count-1)
                        index++;
                        image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri( photoslist[index].LargeUrl , UriKind.Absolute));
                        progess_bar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    }
                    else if (((e.Angle <= 45 && e.Angle >= 0) || (e.Angle < 360 && e.Angle >= 315)) && e.Direction.ToString().Equals("Horizontal"))
                    {
                        progess_bar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                        if (index > 0)
                            index--;
                        else
                            index = 0;
                        image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri( photoslist[index].LargeUrl, UriKind.Absolute));
                        progess_bar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the Source property on Image does **not** block running thread till download completes so code will continue executing and your progress bar will be invisible immediately.

If you want to provide true progress bar functionality then you'll have to manually download the images and update progress bar based on progress. However, images in general are not big files. You are better off showing some sort of loading animation till image download completes.

Comment: So I would basically await on a downloadasync function of a webclient and show the download progress based on that. I did think of this, but will be coding a bit more than what I intended to. 
There must be an easier way

Comment: You have to write code if you want to catch download progress, there is no other way to get notified otherwise.

Comment: yup, I did more research awaiting async calls is the way to get progress 
Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

For those interested I have rough code solution below which works. (be aware that it is not optimized, you can work on it)

```
private void GestureListener_Flick(object sender, FlickGestureEventArgs e)
        {
            if (((e.Angle <= 180 && e.Angle >= 135) || (e.Angle < 225 && e.Angle > 180)) && e.Direction.ToString().Equals("Horizontal"))
            {
                if (index < photoslist.Count - 1)
                {
                    index++;
                    downloadImage();
                }
                //image_big.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri( photoslist[index].LargeUrl , UriKind.Absolute));
            }
            else if (((e.Angle <= 45 && e.Angle >= 0) || (e.Angle < 360 && e.Angle >= 315)) && e.Direction.ToString().Equals("Horizontal"))
            {
                if (index > 0)
                {
                    index--;
                    downloadImage();
                }
                //image_big.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri( photoslist[index].LargeUrl, UriKind.Absolute));

            }
        }

        private void downloadImage()
        {
            progess_bar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            wc.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(wc_OpenReadCompleted);
            wc.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(photoslist[index].LargeUrl, UriKind.Absolute), wc);
        }

        private void wc_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Error == null && !e.Cancelled)
            {
                try
                {
                    BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
                    image.SetSource(e.Result);
                    image_big.Source = image;
                    progess_bar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Cannot get the feed right now.Please try later.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```